# How to get the series expansion?

Tags: binomial-theorem

I found a series expansion of $(1+2x)^{1/2x}$  is:
$$1+  \frac{1}{2x} 2x + \frac{\frac{1}{2x} (\frac{1}{2x}-1)}{2!} (2x)^2 +  \frac{\frac{1}{2x} (\frac{1}{2x}-1) (\frac{1}{2x}-2)}{3!} (2x)^3  $$

But which law and how they have got this expansion. Is it related to the the binomial theorem $(1+x)^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression isn't true with the exponent $\frac1{2x}$ since in this case we should write

$$(1+2x)^{1/2x}=\exp\left(\frac1{2x}\log(1+2x)\right)$$
but if the expression has the form $(1+2x)^{1/2\alpha}$ with constant exponent then we have
$$(1+2x)^{1/2\alpha}=1+  \frac{1}{2\alpha} 2x + \frac{\frac{1}{2\alpha} (\frac{1}{2\alpha}-1)}{2!} (2x)^2 +  \frac{\frac{1}{2\alpha} (\frac{1}{2\alpha}-1) (\frac{1}{2\alpha}-2)}{3!} (2x)^3+\cdots $$ and it's just the Tayor expansion.

Comment: nice catch. I missed that.

Comment: I forgot to indicate that, There was an limit that x tends to zero. Can We now write than in taylor form?

Comment: Yes The taylor expaansion which I wrote   is only valid for $x$ close to $0$.@ComplexGuy